# tesseract 4.0, reading text from a reciept image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I was trying to extract text from a receipt image uploaded as image1 and image2.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

After scaling and removing noise from the second image, the tesseract is able to extract text pretty well, whereas after applying the same transformations to the first image also there is no improvement in the text output.

I tried binarization, blurr function, sharpening also in first image. Still there is no improvement.

Is there any way to extract text from image1 ? I read about tesseract training, will that help in this scenario. If so how we can do that?